# FolderId got by powershell does not match folderId got by ews

Tags: powershell, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

1.FolderId got by powershell `Get-MailboxFolderStatistics` does not match folderId got by ews get folder.I have got folderId by powershell Get-MailboxFolderStatistics,but it does not match which got by ews get-folder.How can I convert it?

Powershell followed:
[image]
EWS followed:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-work-with-folders-by-using-ews-in-exchange

[image]

Comment: We can't see your monitor. We don't know what `find-item` and we don't know what `parentFolderIds` is. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That is folderId got by powershell does not match which got by EWS.Is there any relation between them?

Answer (score 0):

Get-MailboxFolderstaistics return the OWAId (or what EWS classifies as the OWAid). To use that in EWS you need to convert it using the convertId operation in EWS eg

```html
function ConvertId{
    param (
            $OwaId = "$( throw 'OWAId is a mandatory Parameter' )"
          )
    process{
        $aiItem = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AlternateId
        $aiItem.Mailbox = $MailboxName
        $aiItem.UniqueId = $OwaId
        $aiItem.Format = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.IdFormat]::OwaId
        $convertedId = $service.ConvertId($aiItem, [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.IdFormat]::EwsId)
        return $convertedId.UniqueId
    }
}

## Get Empty Folders from EMS
get-mailboxfolderstatistics $MailboxName | Where-Object{$_.FolderType -eq "User Created" -band $_.ItemsInFolderAndSubFolders -eq 0} | ForEach-Object{
    "Processing Folder " + $_.FolderPath
    try{
        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
        $urlEncodedId = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($_.FolderId.ToString())
        $folderid= new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId((Convertid $urlEncodedId))
        $ewsFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$folderid)
        ##Process Folder
    }
    catch{
    $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I install EWS module on powershell?My server is 2012 which does not support it.And will it request EWS with http/https?

Comment: You don't have to you can use the raw SOAP/XML instead it just a lot more complex code